Power Query Self-Referencing Table Adds Rows (but not exactly double); Filtering out table didn't work
I have a table generated via a query that I'm trying to add a "Comment" column all the way to the right.  I was doing this by creating a Self-Referencing query, and then merging them in the original query, as per this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHgv_gWw7iQ.  I have around 3700 rows, and when I merge them, I end up with something like 5400.  So not a doubling up of everthing.  I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abfXF-WPW7A, and, "yes" this recursion thing happens to me too, although, as mentioned, not a doubling.  Also, filtering out the table doesn't help anyway.
In this simple example, the rows that duplicate tend to be where there's already a multiple.  So I would end up with 1 Alice row, 1 Bob row, 4 Carol rows, 1 Dave row, and 4 Ethan rows.  Any ideas?


I figured this out.  It's because when I was doing the Merge Queries (first video), the column I used to Match essentially was not unique (I was using the First Name column in my posted example).  So I added and index column, and used that index column as the "matching" column across the two tables.
